# How do I use IDF in a spark pipeline?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I really want to use the new pipeline concept that spark is pushing, but as the IDF object needs to be fit on data and then transform it I don't know how to use it. I want to do this;

```
Tokenizer tk = new Tokenizer()
            .setInputCol("text")
            .setOutputCol("words");
HashingTF tf = new HashingTF()
            .setNumFeatures(1000)
            .setInputCol(tk.getOutputCol())
            .setOutputCol("rawFeatures");
IDF idf = new IDF()
            .setInputCol(tf.getOutputCol())
            .setOutputCol("IDFFeatures");
Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline()
            .setStages(new PipeLineStage[] {tk, tf, idf})
```

but unless I've misunderstood that doesn't work with idf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not complicated at all, if you check [Official Pipeline Example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline), they do exactly as you. However, you noticed that most of those `stages` (`Estimators` or `Transformers`) must be fitted first, but in the example they don't do that, why?. Because, developers considered this, and programmed the `Pipeline` class in a way to make it do this step for you (all models instantiations, fit, transformations and predictions are done inside).

Comment: This answer is correct, however my understanding is that IDF should only be applied to the training set and not  to the testing set, because IDF is based on term frequency throughout the corpus. In that case how can I manipulate the pipeline to apply IDF only in the training stage?

Comment: @danieln well you could split the DataFrame into two different Datatrames and use one of them to feed the pipeline

Comment: Right, but the pipeline would still apply IDF to the testing set.

Comment: @danieln No because you will pass to the pipeline only the training data. You will keep the other one (validation) outside and untouched.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly, IDF.fit() on the training set produces IDFModel and IDFModel.transform() on the testing set will calculate IDF based on the training set.